# Netbeans 8.1 scanf() function does not work properly

Tags: c, netbeans, scanf, netbeans-8.1

I'm running Netbeans 8.1 on a Windows 10 x86 64-bit computer, I have the project's Run>Console Type set to Standard Output because neither internal nor external terminal have worked for me with any other source I've made--for which standard output had. In any case, here is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
int main(void){

float original_amount, amount_with_tax;

printf("Enter an amount: ");
scanf("%f", &original_amount);
amount_with_tax = original_amount * 1.05f;
printf("With tax added: $%.2f\n", amount_with_tax);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and here is the output:

> 3
>    Enter an amount: With tax added: $3.15

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4s)

As you can see, the scan function is reading in the number before the program even prints "Enter an amount:". Also, after I commented out the scanf function, it printed both printf statements as expected. I have been wrestling with this problem for a while now and any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try `printf("Enter an amount: ");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: That worked! Is this only necessary because I'm using the standard output as my run console? And if so, should I just put it at the beginning of any program that will use a function accessing the buffer? thanks

Comment: Perhaps I think that's because you are running in the IDE. Probably you not need  if you want to run directly on the console.

Answer (score 0):

**ISO/IEC 9899:201x**:

> ### Files
>
> … When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line
>   character is encountered. …

Your standard output stream seems to be line buffered, which is most often so.

> try `printf("Enter an amount: ");fflush(stdout);` – BLUEPIXY
>
> That worked! Is this only necessary because I'm using the standard output as my run console?

No, other streams opened by your program may even be *fully buffered*.

> And if so, should I just put it at the beginning of any program that
>   will use a function accessing the buffer?

Putting `fflush(stdout)` at the beginning of a program won't do, since it outputs only once what is already in the `stdout` buffer. But you can use `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` there.